# Fast-foward a real-time java simulation

Tags: java

I'm doing a simulation of a Bank where I have one queue and three cashiers; the objective is to obtain statistics, for example the average wait time of the customers. Every cashier has a different attention time and a new client comes enters the bank every 1.5 minutes. The bank just runs 5 hours. Now, is there a way I could program it in real time (cause I think its the only way) and then some way fast foward the jvm in order to get the statistics sooner?

Comment: I'm sure that's simply just where a math equation would come in... Not "fast forward" the jvm... which in technical terms no.. you can't

Comment: Now I may be completely missing the mark here, but you should develop around a concept of a `tick` where one tick = one unit of irl time. To speed up or slow down time within your simulation, you just increase the number of `ticks` per second.

Comment: "real-time" is contradictory to "fast-forward", but if you have a simulation, then you have a concept of time-periods, all of which you just divide. For example, dividing by 2 would cause the simulation to go twice as fast.

Comment: Note that i have the code saved (from which i wrote the pseudo-code in an answer below). You you want to verify your own coding solution aginst that, using a few cases, i'll be happy to run them here and pass over the results. Just write the starting parms here in commentary!

Comment: Also note: This problem does absolutely not require any "time (or time speedup) simulation". It is a simple matter of pre-generating a list of events (customer walks in) and then stepping through them, one by one. The problem if fully solvable and the result is accurate, down to fp precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot fast-forward the JVM, but you can program this to simulate in non real-time to get statistics soon. Play with variables that represents time in a small enough unit of time (for example in seconds) and do the simulation normally, increasing the time in one unit. For the queue you can use a deque containing the instants when every client entered the bank, and then iterate over time.

```
private static int TOTAL_TIME = 5*3600; // Hours to seconds
private static int TIME_BETWEEN_CLIENTS = 90; // In seconds
private static int CASHIERS = 3;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create cashiers and assign range of attentions time to each cashier, in seconds
    // This is an example for cashiers with 3, 3~6 and 4.5~15 minutes
    List<Cashier> cashiers = new ArrayList<Cashier>(CASHIERS);
    cashiers.add(new Cashier(180, 180));
    cashiers.add(new Cashier(180, 360));
    cashiers.add(new Cashier(270, 900));

    int time = 0; // Counting variable in seconds
    int waitingTime = 0; // Save here all waiting time for all clients
    int clients = 0; // Save here all clients

    // Register here all available cashiers
    ArrayList<Cashier> freeCashiers;

    Deque<Integer> queue = new ArrayDeque<Integer>(); // Clients queue

    // Iterate until bank closes and all clients have been attended
    while (time < TOTAL_TIME || !queue.isEmpty()) {
        // New client if the bank is not closed
        if (time < TOTAL_TIME && time%TIME_BETWEEN_CLIENTS == 0) {
            queue.add(time); // Register customer start waiting time
            clients++;
        }

        // Check for free cashiers when someone is on queue
        if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            freeCashiers = new ArrayList<Cashier>(CASHIERS);
            for (Cashier c : cashiers) {
                if (c.isFree(time))
                    freeCashiers.add(c);
            }

            if (!freeCashiers.isEmpty()) {
                // Register spent time for the removed client
                waitingTime += time - queue.removeFirst();

                // Select a random cashier from all the available cashiers
                Cashier randomAvailableCashier = freeCashiers.get(Cashier.RANDOM.nextInt(freeCashiers.size()));

                // Register when the randomly selected cashier will be free again
                randomAvailableCashier.attendNewClient(time);
            }
        }
        time++; // Adds one second
    }

    // Calculate statistics
    int avgWaitingTime = waitingTime/clients; // In seconds

    System.out.println("Average waiting time on queue: " + formatTime(avgWaitingTime));
}

/**
 * Formats a time in minutes and seconds
 * @param time the time in seconds
 * @return the formatted time
 */
private static String formatTime(int time) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    if (time > 60) {
        result.append(time/60).append(" minutes");
        time %= 60;
        if (time > 0)
            result.append(" and ");
        else
            result.append(".");
    }
    if (time > 0)
        result.append(time).append(" seconds.");
    return result.toString();
}
```

And the Cashier class:

```
public class Cashier {
    public static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    private int minAttentionTime, maxAttentionTime, endTime;

    /**
     * Constructs new Cashier with a range of possible attention time, in seconds
     * @param minAttentionTime in seconds
     * @param maxAttentionTime in seconds
     */
    public Cashier(int minAttentionTime, int maxAttentionTime) {
        this.minAttentionTime = minAttentionTime;
        this.maxAttentionTime = maxAttentionTime;
        endTime = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Register end time with a random attention time in the range.
     * @param currentTime the current time in seconds
     */
    public void attendNewClient(int currentTime) {
        endTime = currentTime + getRandomNumberInRange(minAttentionTime, maxAttentionTime);
    }

    /**
     * Returns if this cashier is available
     * @param currentTime the current time in seconds
     * @return true if this cashier is free, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isFree(int currentTime) {
        return currentTime >= endTime;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a random number in range [min, max]
     * @param min the minimum number, inclusive
     * @param max the maximum number, inclusive
     * @return a random number in range [min, max]
     */
    private int getRandomNumberInRange(int min, int max) {
        return RANDOM.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(endTime);
    }
}
```

With this implementation a new client will go to a random free cashier.

Comment: And what if every cashier has the same possibility of being chosen? Should a random number be generated, divided by three and then the value tested in order to choose?

Comment: No, if you divide a random number you would access to an out of bounds position. You could generate a random number in range with Random nextInt(arrayLenght), but you've to test all positions, so the best way is to change the array for a list and do Collections.shuffle(cashiersEndTime) to randomize positions before the iteration and then test from the first position, as actually.

Comment: It's not working for small waiting times, Im trying with the cashier ONE having waiting times from 0.5 to 1.5 minutes, cashier TWO from 0.5 to 2 minutes, and cahsier THREE from 0.5 to 2.5 minutes. Also with the clients chosing randomly if there is more than one free cashier.

Comment: I've updated the code, with a Cashier class that makes it more understandable and a list of free cashiers, which allows random selection (instead of shuffle the clients list). Furthermore I've done that every cashier has a range of possible waiting times (as in your comment). If you want a fixed time, pass the same value for min and max.

About adding cashiers with slow waiting time: it works, but the result will be a 0 average waiting time, because when a client arrives there will be a cashier available for sure and then client haven't to wait.

Answer (score 0):

If you instead used a queue system, you could go very quickly. The queue would contain events that are coming up, and a timestamp of when they are due. The queue would be organized by event timestamp. Initially, you could seed this queue with a new customer every 1.5 minutes, and an event for the bank closing in 5 hours. Then you pop the first event off the queue, figure out what that triggers. For example, the first event of a customer entering causes you to increase the customer wait line count. A teller becoming free causes the wait line count to reduce and an agent-customer activity that last for some random time length. This causes a new event (another teller being free) to be placed in the queue. When a teller being free occurs, and there are no customers in line, you set an empty teller flag, which would be checked when you next handle a customer entering event. You could quickly run through an entire day within a few seconds with approach, and you can gather statistics on whatever you want at each event.

Comment: There is no way I can seed a queue and then enter other events in between. I would just be able to enqueue behind the closing bank event, right?

Comment: With a stock queue object, correct, but you could easily write your own queue functions that work on a standard list of event objects. Then your push method could insert the new event on the timestamp or the event.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to use formulas here is my math. If some cashier has time T1 for processing one person then this cashier processes 1/T1 people per time unit. Number of people processed by N cashiers are added. Coming back from processing speed to processing time we get common time for processing one person by all cashiers:

```
Tcom = 1/(1/T1 + 1/T2 + ... + 1/Tn)
```

You compare this time with your 1.5 minutes and if Tcom <= 1.5 minutes then your queue will be mostly empty or consist of 1 person (and average waiting time will be around half of average of Ti). In case Tcom > 1.5 minutes your queue will grow constantly by one person each Tcom - 1.5 minutes. Queue length at the end of working day will be Lavg = 5 * 60 / (Tcom - 15) people (and half of it in average). Each person in head of the queue is removed from it each Tcom minutes. It means that average waiting time is going to be `Tcom * Lavg / 2`.

I know it's all very rough estimates but why not?

Answer (score 0):

(You deleted your other almost identical question. Here's the long answer i wrote before knowing that. Good that you had this copy, so i didn't waste my time)

Here is the functional pseudo. I actually coded it, out of curiosity.

I use a computer language called APL, which is most likely unknown to you, hence pseudo.

You need to create a 2-dimensional table, ie. an array, with 6 columns. If you cannot create 2-dimensional arrays, you can alternatively (hopefully) create 1-dimensional arrays, ie. lists, where one list holds the values of one column in the table. The important thing is that you can index into arrays. If you use listst, you must extend the code a bit.

You will only work with integer values.

The solution is that you pre-create a table, which holds the customer arrival times in column 1. All other columns hold zeroes to start with. Then you loop through the table, updating the other columns, row-by-row, using a help variable for the cashiers.

Once you have looped through all rows in the table, you extract the desired results from it, by additional calculation.

For the cashiers actions, you need another 2-dimensional table, holding [nr of cashiers] rows and 3 columns. Similarly, you can replace it with 3 lists, one per table column. Columns 2 and 3 in this small table accumulate each cashiers tim ethey spent serving a customer, and time they spent waiting for customers.

You do not work with clock times, but with seconds since day start. For example 8am equals 28800 (ie. number of seconds elapsed since day start). To this value, you can easily add customer arrival times with 90 seconds increments (or any, arbitrary amount of seconds intervals). You pre-create customer arrival times for *the entire 5-hour (or any hour) day*.

```
// Create a table with 6 columns. Columns are
//  1: Customer arrival timestamp (first value is 28800) [seconds since midnight]
//  2: The timestamp the customer was attended [seconds since midnight]
//  3: The time a customer had to wait [seconds]
//  4: The time the customer spent with the cashier [seconds]
//  5: The timestamp the customer leaves the bank [seconds since midnight]
//  6: The cashier # that provided service, 1,2 or 3 in your case
//  
// If the customer arrive at regular 90 s intervals, the table now looks like this
//  (10 first rows only, but you must populate it up to bank closing time)
//  which would need ca 200 rows. Call this table "Cust":
//  28800 0 0 0 0 0
//  28890 0 0 0 0 0
//  28980 0 0 0 0 0
//  29070 0 0 0 0 0
//  29160 0 0 0 0 0
//  29250 0 0 0 0 0
//  29340 0 0 0 0 0
//  29430 0 0 0 0 0
//  29520 0 0 0 0 0
//  29610 0 0 0 0 0
// 
// Create a variable for the cashiers, 1 row per cashier. Columns are:
//  1. An "action timestamp", initially 28800 [seconds since midnight] 
//  2. Accumulation of cashiers attention time [seconds]
//  3. Accumulation of cashiers wait/slack time [seconds]
//  
//  The table now looks like this
//   (add more rows if you have more cashiers). Call this table "Cash":
//   28800 0 0
//   28800 0 0
//   28800 0 0

rows = [numers of rows in Cust]
i = 0

:While i < rows
 // Note! This pseudocode uses 0-origin, ie. array[0] is the first element
 // Find the row number of Cash with the _smallest_ value in it's column 1
    row = [0, 1 or 2] // You commonly first find the smallest number, then compare it against each row. The match is the row with smallest number.
 // Attention time for this customer (you said "range of"), 
 //  we use 265 s now, for simplicity, but you can give time another value each time
    time = 265

    :If Cust[i;0]<Cash[row;0]              // Customer has waited
        Cust[i;1]=Cash[row;0]              // Timestamp this Customer got service
        Cust[i;3]=time                     // Time spent with cashier
        Cust[i;4]=Cash[row;0]+time         // Timestamp customer leaves the bank
        Cust[i;5]=row                      // Which cashier provided the service
        Cash[row;1]+=time                  // Increase accumulated attend time for cashier
        Cash[row;0]+=time                  // Next timestamp this cashier is free
    :Else                                  // Cashier had free time (bank was empty until now)
        Cash[row;2]+=Cust[i;0]-Cash[row;0] // Accumulate freetime for cashier
        Cash[row;1]+=time                  // Accumulate attend time for cashier
        Cust[i;1]=Cust[i;0]                // There was no wait time for customer
        Cust[i;3]=time                     // Time spent with cashier
        Cust[i;4]=Cust[i;0]+time           // Timestamp customer leaves the bank
        Cust[i;5]=row                      // Which cashier provided the service
        Cash[row;0]=Cust[i;0]+time         // Next timestamp this cashier is free
    :End
    i+←1
:End

// Resolve customer wait times, equals [time attended] - [time arrived] and
//  populate 3rd column of Cust (you must probably loop), row by row
Cust[n;2] = Cust[n;1] - Cust[n;0] // n = each row

//  Cust now looks like this:
//  28800 28800 0 265 29065 0
//  28890 28890 0 265 29155 1
//  28980 28980 0 265 29245 2
//  29070 29070 0 265 29335 0
//  29160 29160 0 265 29425 1
//  29250 29250 0 265 29515 2
//  29340 29340 0 265 29605 0
//  29430 29430 0 265 29695 1
//  29520 29520 0 265 29785 2
//  29610 29610 0 265 29875 0

fnAvg = [function that calculates the average of a list of numbers]

// Extract the results
//  Note: For example "Cust[;2]" means _all rows in column 2 of Cust_, ie. a list of numbers
//  You don't need to create any lists though, just loop through them all and calculate/accumulate
  'Nr of customers attended immediately: ',[number of zeroes in Cust[;2]]
  'Nr of customers who waited: ',[number of non-zeroes in Cust[;2]]
  'Wait times: ',[all numbers in Cust[;2] - this is a list of numbers]
  'Average wait times: ',[avg Cust[;2]]
  'Average wait times (only those who waited): ',[avg Cust[;2] elements that are non-zero]
  'Total cashier attend times: ',Cash[;1]
  'Total cashier free times: ',Cash[;2]

//  And finally a verification calc (backwards calc, just for curiosity)
  'Check: Total customer existance time: ',Cust[i-1;4]-Cust[0;0]
  'Check: Cashier total times (should be close to above value): ',[sum of Cash[n;1 2]]
```

The result with the arguments above is (numbers are seconds unless otherwise said):

```
Nr of customers attended immediately:  10
Nr of customers who waited:  0
Wait times: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Average wait times: 0
Average wait times (only those who waited): 0
Total cashier attend times:  1060 795 795
Total cashier free times:  15 100 190
Check: Total customer existance time:  1075
Check: Cashier total times (should be close to previous row):  1075 895 985
```

If you have 20 customers arriving, and use random attend times between 100 and 480 seconds, you may get for example:

```
Nr of customers served immediately:  8
Nr of customers waited:  12
Wait times: 0 0 0 0 0 14 0 0 0 200 120 147 183 122 149 111 185 178 244 218
Average wait times: 93.55
Average wait times (only those who waited): 155.9166667
Total cashier attend times:  1820 1836 1819
Total cashier free times:  217 197 309
Check: Total customer existance time:  2128
Check: Cashier total times (should be close to previous row):  2037 2033 2128

with Cust (edited: was erratically Cash) table looking like this:

28800 28800   0 160 28960 0
28890 28890   0 433 29323 1
28980 28980   0 114 29094 2
29070 29070   0 194 29264 0
29160 29160   0 117 29277 2
29250 29264  14 149 29413 0
29340 29340   0 470 29810 2
29430 29430   0 390 29820 1
29520 29520   0 417 29937 0
29610 29810 200 253 30063 2
29700 29820 120 389 30209 1
29790 29937 147 155 30092 0
29880 30063 183 445 30508 2
29970 30092 122 169 30261 0
30060 30209 149 216 30425 1
30150 30261 111 403 30664 0
30240 30425 185 408 30833 1
30330 30508 178 220 30728 2
30420 30664 244 173 30837 0
30510 30728 218 200 30928 2
```

Try with populating the 1st column of Cust with different, more random customer arrivbal times, and for each iteration, the time with values that fit your real environment better.

This pseudo supports both "bank temporarily empty" and "long que all time", and also supports the "Once the bank closes after 5 hours, every client gets attended"-criterion (the remaining customers will be cleaned up").

Good luck! :-)